# What is the meaning of each part of the name of the parquet file Spark creates?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a parquet file within a partition with the following name -

```
part-00000-e2c9a357-3b03-439f-96ed-5febc883daf7.c000.gz.parquet
```

Is there a spacial meaning to the following parts of:

1. `e2c9a357`
2. `3b03-439f-96ed`
3. `5febc883daf7`
4. `c000`

Answer (score 3):

`e2c9a357-3b03-439f-96ed-5febc883daf7` → represents the unique ID of the Spark job that wrote this data.

`c000` → indicates the task number (`c` stands for `commit`).